# Focusrite 18i20 to SONY HDR-PJ780VE Camcorder

Tags: audio-recording

I have a Focusrite 18i20 Audio Interface, and want to record the sound when i video my drum sessions on my SONY Camcorder, model no: HDR-PJ780VE

I have tried connecting the headphone 2 outlet on the front of the Focusrite 18i20 directly to the camcorder's Microphone In (pink socket, 3.5mm).  But although the drum recording is good, there is a load of interference/noise/buzz in the recording also.

When I connect my headphones into that same socket (Headphone 2 Outlet), there is no 'noise' to be heard.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely a ground loop between the camera and the interface, which is not present when you are using headphones. Additionally you are likely to have level issues between the camcorder and the interface output. Headphone outputs are generally a higher voltage level than a mic input requires, so you will need to attenuate the input somewhat or use very little gain on the mic input.

Also remember to disable any "Auto Gain Control" on the camera audio input. Input level should be under manual control at all times.